# Unable to do waitforexit while invoking EXE

Tags: c#, powershell, exe, invoke-command

I am running EXE using below code. EXE opens up properly and runs properly. I am facing two issues.

1. is there anything similar to Process.WaitforExit() while invoking PowerShell.Invoke.Once user completes operations on EXE and closes the same,then the remaining execution should continue.
2. The output of EXE is coming as System.Management.ManagementBaseObject. It should contain the executable result.

If I run the EXE using Process.Start, I can achieve both the above results. The output also coming up properly. Please help on this.

```
using (Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
    string remoteScriptPath="e:\shared\test.ex";
    string parameterString="p1";
    runSpace.Open();
    using (Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline())
    {
        RunspaceInvoke invoke = new RunspaceInvoke();
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.Runspace = runSpace;
        ps.AddCommand("invoke-wmimethod");
        ps.AddParameter("class", "Win32_Process");
        ps.AddParameter("name", "Create");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameterString))
        {
            ps.AddParameter("argumentlist", remoteScriptPath);
        }
        else
        {                            
         ps.AddParameter("argumentlist", remoteScriptPath + " " + parameterString);
        }

        Collection<PSObject> psOutput = ps.Invoke();

        if (ps.Streams.Error.Count == 0)
        {
            string result="";

            foreach (PSObject psObject in psOutput)
            {
                if (psObject != null)
                {
                    result += psObject.BaseObject.ToString();
                    result += Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: You already have C# code.. Why do you have to use Powershell from C# to launch another application.. Why not use the `Process` class built in .Net framework, with which, I hear you say you are already getting expected results?

Comment: I want to run exe on remote machine using PowerShell only.

Comment: You are supposed to be the one asking question, but let me ask one :) Are you sure that you'd be able launch an interactive desktop app using PowerShell **remoting**? I have never tried it.. but I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't work as you think it might.. Or may be I am wrong, or may be I am still mis-understanding your scenario.

Comment: Have you tried running something simple like a get-location, just to verify the powershell runspace is working?

Comment: Yes runspace is working fine. I am able to open EXE using the above code. My requirement is that the program execution should stop till the EXE is open. once the EXE closed by user, the program execution should continue. Hope I am able to clarify the requirement.